# How to Generate Barcode using PHP and Display it as an Image on the same page

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, barcode

I want to Generate Bar code (any type) using PHP

I am having a variable where i store a code

```
<?php
    $code= 'f5c9b918c5';
?>
```

so just i want to generate a barcode of this and echo the barcode image where i want ..... 
please help

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is a library for this [BarCode PHP](https://www.barcodebakery.com/en). You just need to include a few files:

```
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');
```

You can generate many types of barcodes, namely 1D or 2D. Add the required library:

```
require_once('class/BCGcode39.barcode.php');
```

Generate the colours:

```
// The arguments are R, G, and B for color.
$colorFront = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$colorBack = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);
```

After you have added all the codes, you will get this way:

[image]
<sub>(source: [barcodebakery.com](https://www.barcodebakery.com/Content/Images/code39/hello.png))</sub>

**Example**

Since several have asked for an example here is what I was able to do to get it done

```
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');

require_once('class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

$code = new BCGcode128();
$code->parse('HELLO');

$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);

$drawing->draw();
$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

If you want to actually create the image file so you can save it then change

```
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
```

to

```
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('image.png', $color_white);
```

Comment: thnx @PraveenKumar hey where i can pass the value of my $code?

Comment: Check out the documentation. You have a lot of options.

Comment: AFAIK, the most complete PHP Software library to generate both linear and bidimensional barcodes is currently tc-lib-barcode (https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode). The source code is fully PSR-2 compliant and can be easily added to your PHP projects using Composer. The original code has been ported and refactored from TCPDF and already used in billions of documents.

Comment: Thanks @NicolaAsuni, but it has been ages since this question was answered!

Comment: this answer would be a lot better if it included at least one example... but thanks all the same.

Comment: @billynoah Yes, right, but this is like an year old answer, without any context. :)

Comment: @NicolaAsuni Thanks for the link, good to know there's a GPL PHP barcode library out there.

Comment: Actually @NicolaAsuni answers is the right one here. Because the answer is referencing a paid service.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul I'll just copy and paste it in my answer to make it better. It wasn't commercial when I posted the answer. Trust me... `:)`

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul It's still free. Check out the Non Commercial license. `:)`

Comment: "free", but not "free". There is a better solution out there, really free.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul Agreed. What am I supposed to do now? It was open source 5 years ago.

Comment: How can I use this with codeigniter 3